# How to load Tableview Pagewise?

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, uitableview, pagination

Hi I am working with the Tableview every thing working fine. Now I want to implement like Page Loading in tableview with out using any web services.I am fetching data from sqlite I need to display in tableview working fine. But how to implement page wise. Suppose per page i need to display 50 rows is it possible?

Comment: do you want something like load more?

Comment: @ivarun yes like pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if (indexPath.row == [yourArray count] -1) {
    [self loadMoreDataFromDatabase];
}
```

Then, count number of pages available for paging using below code:

```
NSString *strSelectData  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@",TABLE NAME];
NSArray *arrResult = [appDel.database lookupAllForSQL:strSelectData];// get data in array
NSInteger pageCount = roundf(arrResult.count/50);
return pageCount;
```

Use below code to get data pagewise:

```
NSInteger numberOfPages = [self countNumberOfPages];

if (numberOfPages > currentPage) {
    currentPage++;

    NSString *selectAllData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM %@ LIMIT %ld*5,50",TABLE NAME,(long)currentPage];

    NSArray *arrSelectAllResult = [appDel.database lookupAllForSQL:selectAllData];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self.tblView reloadData];
    });
}
```

Hope you get basic idea. :)